# How do I trigger hotkeys on AnyTone 878UV?

Tags: ht, equipment-operation, radio-programming, anytone

I've read the manual twice, and watched programming guide videos on youtube, but while I can program hotkey 1-6 just fine, I can't find how to actually trigger them.

I found how to trigger the "Fun key+N" keys, also mentioned in the manual. The green key appears to have the name "Func", even though I can't find that actually in any manual. You long press the green key, and then can trigger 0-9, and * and #.

But what about the "Hotkeys"? How do I trigger them?

Answer (score 3):

Just starting out here I currently don't have the rep-points to upvote his post, but I think that N3CAN is exactly correct. Regrettably the so called HotKeys on the Anytone 878 and 578 just seem to be something like "Links" or shortcuts to submenus, which then can be used as an assigment to one of the function keys, so the name is a little misleading.

I just set up my new 878 and in comparison to the 578 you have less programmable keys available. It is just PF1 and PF2 which are the 2 keys below the PTT, PF3 which is the blue key on top, P1 and P2 which are on front.

Now you can assign functions to short and long key presses of these keys which should make 10 functions programmable. But a few of the functions (like "Monitor" or "Tone Burst") occupy both, the "short-press" and also the "long-press" slot so you lose one "programming slot".

I just managed to assign 8 of them. It sounds like a lot, but it's not as you also have to setup basic functions like: "VFO/Memory", "A/B", "Monitor", "Select TX Power", "Scan", "Reverse", "Send Toneburst", "Select DMR Timeslot" and so on.

You quickly run out of keys to assign to. For example the radio offers "Nuisance delete" for scan mode, which i find very important, but currently I got no key left to assign it to.

Too long, didn't read: I think N3CANs answer is correct and it's a shame because this radio could make good use of a few more programmable function keys.

PS: There's also the Function Key (long press of the green key) and 0-9 key assignment, but it let's you only assign menu shortcuts and no other functions, so that doesn't help either.
If anybody knows more, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Now you should have enough reputation to up-vote.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, after you program the Hot Keys, you then need to apply them to an actual key (PF1, PF2, PF3, P1, P2) to access them. Basically they are like functions that you can define (things that are not otherwise available for key assignment).

If you look at the options that are available for, let's say the PF2 key, Hot Keys 1-6 should be available as options to select. So Program Hot Key 1 to access the SMS menu, then apply that to PF2 and now PF2 will open the SMS menu for you.

Comment: I don't think so. I've certainly set functions to PF1, etc keys, but they seem to be set directly. Both for long and short press.

Answer (score 2):

*The green key appears to have the name "Func", even though I can't find that actually in any manual. You long press the green key, and then can trigger 0-9, and * and #.*

On my brand new 878, a long-press of the **Menu** key acts as the 'Function' button (not sure that's in the manual anywhere, either). The Green key (PF3) is assignable as all the other keys are, but it's not the 'Function' key in my radio.

Comment: Hello Gary, and thanks for answering! Welcome. :-)

Comment: The OP was referring the the key with the green line (the Menu key). The original 878 had a blue PF3 button which he also describes. The green PF3 button was added on the 878UVII.